# Display field set based on dropdown selection yii 2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, show, yii2

I am new to javacripting and Yii2 Framework. Can anyone please help me just to display a set of field values depending on the dropdown selection.

For example, I have in dropdown "*If you are a student or not?*":

- *Yes*
- *No*

If user selects *Yes* then display a div containing other fields to be answered.

I could find answers regarding doing it in general but specifically using Yii 2 I am having problems.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also, use radio buttons for `yes/no` form elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very simple with jquery... and there's a couple ways you can do it, but here's an example:

```
//HTML
<input type="radio" name="student" id="studentY" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="student" id="studentN" /> No

<div id="moreQuestions">
    <p>This is your block containing more fields</p>
</div>

//JS
$('#studentY').click(function(){
    $('#moreQuestions').show();
});

$('#studentN').click(function(){
    $('#moreQuestions').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/95fvgcnn/

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response. I did tried to find a solution but could not find any. Howe ver, I am struggling to get it done within an active form record in yii2 like this:   <?= $form->field($model, 'is_student')->dropDownList(array('2' =>'No','1' => 'Yes')) ?> how to get it done!! I appreciate your kind support!!

Comment: @TechNet PHP is all server-side. You're not going to be able to do any manipulation with PHP after the page is loaded. You'll need javascript to toggle the visibility of elements once they're on the page. Molls223 solution should work for you.

Comment: Thank you! thomas. However, I would like to declare this class within this field in active record and then use the same solution offered by Molls223. Can you please help me further get it done.